# while loop in racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

I am familiar with while loops in other languages but here I have written a small function that computes the derivative of a sum of terms but it only does the first 2 I was wondering if there was a way to alter this to take into account more than 2?

expressions, `E`, are represented as lists so `2x + 2y + x^3` is represented as `(+ (* 2 x) (* 2 y) (expt x 3))`

note that I already have functions written to compute the exponential but it is part of a sum and it stops after the first 2

```
(define (make-sum v1 v2)
  (list '+ v1 v2))

(define (diff-sum x E)
  (make-sum (diff x (first-operator E)) (diff x (last-operator E))))
```

Answer (score 17):

In professional-level Racket, [for loops](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/for.html) are a standard approach to do something to a sequence.  For example, the following produces a simple multiplication table:

```
(define numbers (list 1 2 3 4 5 6))
(for/list ([item numbers])
  (list item (* item 2) (* item 3)))
```

It's a loop that walks through each number, processes it, and produces a new list of results.  Fairly standard; almost every programming language has a notion of iteration across a collection.

In the kind of Racket that you'd have to write for an introductory computer science class, you might have to resort to explicit recursion or a higher order function like [map](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/map..rkt%29._map%29%29) instead, depending on your instructor.  These other ways of expressing iteration have the same power as the above loop: we just phrase it a little differently.

For example, the same computation to create the small multiplication table above would be expressed as the following with explicit recursion:

```
(define (my-loop numbers)
  (cond [(empty? numbers) '()]
        [else
         (define item (first numbers))
         (cons (list item (* item 2) (* item 3))
               (my-loop (rest numbers)))]))
(my-loop numbers)
```

and implicitly with the use of `map`:

```
(define (f item)
  (list item (* item 2) (* item 3)))
(map f numbers)
```